# Can't insert non-const value in unordered_map of references

Tags: c++, reference, constants, unordered-map

I'm trying to create 2 std::unordered_map, one holds <A, int> and the second one holds <int&, A&>.
I'll explain at the end why I want to do this if you're curious.

My problem is that k_i has value of type std::reference_wrapper, k_i.insert doesn't work. But if I make k_i to have value std::reference_wrapper<**const** A>, the insert works.

I just can't figure out why is this and I am curious.

**<<<<<Edit:**
The thing is that find returns `std::pair<const Ket, T>` as stated by
Eljay in the comments. Because of this, the second std::unordered_map needs to have the value const.
**<<<<<**

Code:
Compiler: g++ version 10.1
Compile flags: -Wall -Wextra -std=c++20

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

class A {
public:
  A(const int x) : x(x) {
    std::cout << "A::A(const int x) : x(" << x << ")\n";
  }

  A(const A& a) {
    std::cout << "A::A {" << x << "} (const A& a {" << a.x << "} )\n";
    x = a.x;
  }

  A(A&& a) {
    std::cout << "A::A {" << x << "} (A&& a {" << a.x << "} )\n";
    x = a.x;
  }

  A& operator=(const A& a) {
    std::cout << "A::operator= {" << x << "} (const A& a)\n";
    x = a.x;
    return *this;
  }

  A& operator=(A&& a) {
    std::cout << "A::operator= {" << x << "} (A&& a)\n";
    x = a.x;
    return *this;
  }

  ~A() {
    std::cout << "A::~A(" << x << ")\n";
  }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const A& dt);

  int x;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const A& dt) {
    return os << dt.x;
}

template <typename K, typename V, typename... args>
void print_um(const std::unordered_map<K, V, args...> &umap) {
    for (const auto &[x, y] : umap) {
        std::cout << "(" << x << "," << std::ref(y).get() << "); ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

template <typename T>
struct MyHash {
    std::size_t operator()(T const& s) const noexcept {
        return std::hash<int>{}(std::ref(s).get());
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct MyEquals {
    constexpr bool operator()(const T &lhs, const T &rhs) const {
        return lhs == rhs;
    }
};

struct MyHash_A {
    std::size_t operator()(A const& s) const noexcept {
        return std::hash<int>{}(s.x);
    }
};

struct MyEquals_A {
    constexpr bool operator()(const A &lhs, const A &rhs) const {
        return lhs.x == rhs.x;
    }
};

int main() {

    std::unordered_map<A, int, MyHash_A, MyEquals_A> k_s;
    std::unordered_map<std::reference_wrapper<int>, std::reference_wrapper<const A>, MyHash<std::reference_wrapper<int>>, MyEquals<std::reference_wrapper<int>>> k_i;
{
    A a(5);
    std::cout << "1----\n";
    k_s[a] = 12;
    std::cout << "2----\n";
}
    std::cout << "3----\n";
    print_um<>(k_s);


    std::cout << "4----\n";
    A a(5);
    std::cout << "5----\n";
    auto it = k_s.find(a);
    std::cout << "6----\n";
    k_i.emplace((*it).second, (*it).first);
    // // k_i[(*it).second] = ref_name;


    std::cout << "7----\n";
    print_um<>(k_s);
    std::cout << "8----\n";
    print_um<>(k_i);

    std::cout << "9----\n";
    int x = 12;
    int &ref = x;
    auto is_there = k_i.find(ref);
    if (is_there != k_i.end()) {
        std::cout << "elem: " << (*is_there).second.get() << "\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "why? :(\n";
    }
    std::cout << "10---\n";
    return 0;
}
```

As to why I create this code, I was thinking to be able to access some data by value or by key interchangeably (is there some better data structure? ). Like an username and a token, sometimes I have one, other times I have the other and using references I ensure that I don't waste space. Ofc, if one value has to change, I would invalidate the bucket position in the unordered_map because of the key, but I would treat that problem at a later date. Another motive is to learn some more C++ and test its limits (or mine).

Comment: not quite sure what you mean with "you don't waste space"; your space will be spent on the map, mostly, not on the addresses of objects should you decide to store (smart) pointers in them.

Comment: Yeah, I know I could have gotten away with using smart_pointers, but the purpose of this experiment was to have an excuse to learn references better and not rely on pointers so much in the future. And this part I can't understand, why it works if I use **const** there :)) .. cppreference took me so far (0_0;)

Comment: Are you aware that associative containers' keys must be constant?

Comment: I don't think so, if you don't mean that I would invalidate the bucket if I change the key from "outside". Can you elaborate a little more or give me a more clear search term?

Comment: @RobertLica think about it logically: you have some tree-like structure keeping the keys organized, so that lookups can be done quicker than comparing all stored keys with the one the user supplies. Now, you make these keys mutable. Suddenly, your tree structure can't be up-to-date with the keys! That breaks the whole idea. But I agree, I don't find the explicit `const` type requirement.

Comment: One alternative to what you are looking for might be [Boost.Bimap](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html)

Comment: Declaring containers of references is asking for trouble.  Especially when the referenced items are in another container.  What is your reason for doing so?  Did you take into account that adding items to a en unordered_map can shuffle things around and invalidate all of your references ?  That's UB at its finest.

Comment: The `value_type` of a map's entry pair is `std::pair<const Key, T>`.

Comment: Ok, now I got it. Yeah, it makes sense, I didn't observe that find returns the key as const.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [UnorderedAssociativeContainer requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/UnorderedAssociativeContainer):

> For `std::unordered_map` and `std::unordered_multimap` the value type is `std::pair<const Key, T>`.

In your code `k_s` is `unordered_map<A, int>`, so the value type is `pair<const A, int>`. In here:

```cpp
auto it = k_s.find(a);
```

you get a "pointer" to such pair, and type of `(*it).first` is `const A`.

Your `k_i` is `unordered_map<..., ref<A>>` and when you do insert here:

```cpp
k_i.emplace(..., (*it).first);
```

you essentially attempt to initialize `ref<A>` with `const A`, which obviously cannot work.

When you change `k_i` type to `unordered_map<..., ref<const A>>`, then you initialize `ref<const A>` with `const A`, which is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Many have mentioned in the comment that Key type must be `const`. However the OP seems to wonder why the value type in `k_i` also need to be a `const`.

The reason for that is because you are referencing the key from `k_s`, which would be `const A`, and you can not reference it with a non-const reference.

To properly declare `k_s`, you might want to do something like:

```cpp
std::unordered_map<
    std::reference_wrapper<decltype(k_s)::value_type::second_type>, 
    std::reference_wrapper<decltype(k_s)::value_type::first_type>,
    yourHash, yourComp
> k_s;
```

---

One alternative solution for you is to use another container that actually supports bidirectional lookup, such as [Boost.Bimap](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html).